# Continuation for Cancelled Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to set the continuation task after it got cancelled. But I am not able to handle the exception internally.

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
}, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    t.Exception.Handle((e) => true);
    Console.WriteLine("You  have cancelled the task");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop the task");
Console.ReadLine();
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
task.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Press enter to end the application");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The exception is not handled by the code. If i wrap the code with a try block I get an error saying "Object instance not set to the reference of an object".

Any idea?

Comment: What exception would like to handle?

Comment: OperationCanceledException, the on I am throwing

Comment: Why are you throwing the exception at all? The task's IsCancelled flag is set by the token, not the exception

Comment: If you do not throw the exception outside users of the task won't see anything different because the task will just have a RanToCompletion state.

Comment: Pass the token to the `OperationCanceledException` or even better use `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. TPL will check if the exception is connected with the token. If not (as in your case since the exception contains a default token with IsCancellationRequested == false) it will treat the exception as external and change task status to faulted.